# Help me understand if this new product using magnetism could work

Tags: magnetic-fields

I'm not sure if this type of question falls in line here, or if the the thing I'm about to describe even falls under physics, as my lack of understanding of science and especially magnets is well...lacking.

I had an idea that I ran with that would allow you to use **socks infused with metallic filament, that could attach and detach from magnetically charged shoe soles, to create a very minimalist shoe**. Is it a useful idea, who knows, but thats a question for the business stack not physics.

Allow me to show an image of the idea and I will go into depth below:

[image]

This is a top down view of the sole portion of the shoe.

The gray circles are strong neodymium magnets in the heel as well as the front of the shoe, these will be used to attach to your feet via the metallic infused socks on your feet. The brown squares are thin steel plates. Along the soles z-index the steel plate is arranged above the magnet, so if it were to be pushed toward the magnet (it is somewhat free floating along the x-axis) it would actually be sliding in above the magnet.

The idea is when you want to take off the shoes you need a way to disengage the magnets so the soles arent stuck to your socks forever. These steel plates are meant to slide between the magnets and sock (still encased within the soles) to block/redirect the magnetism disengaging the pull between magnet and sock ([This source says steel can block/redirect magnetism](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=shielding-materials)). But how to get the steel plate to slide over on top of the magnet? Notice the small red/blue line on the outer edge of the plates? I want that to be another magnetic bar, since the two outer edges are opposites they will repel each other when you put your feet together pushing the plate over the magnet and allowing you to remove the shoe.

I actually started to try it out in the sense that I went to Home Depot and bought a neodymium magnet with 6 pound pull. Dug scissors into the side of an old shoe under the fabric and shoved the magnet in, put a second magnet it my sock and tried to get it to stick to my foot. It did but not very well, so I stopped and came here. I'm sure there are strong magnets, better ways to embed the magnet without burying it under .25in of fabric, etc. so I'm curious if it is even possible before continuing.

**1. Is anything I just said possible or remotely scientific?

2. Would strong neodymium magnets actually be able to hold to your feet if you were wearing metallic socks?

3. If so, would a steel plate between your socks and the magnet disengage the pull so you could remove the shoe?

4. If so, would the mechanism described to push the plate over the magnet work?**

Comment: What keeps the mud off the sides of my socks?

Comment: Why not just try it out? Are these magnets very expensive?   I am not trying to stop you asking the question, it's just that I personally would try it out.

Comment: @CountTo10 I actually started to try it out in the sense that I went to Home Depot and bought a neodymium magnet  with 6 pound pull. Dug scissors into the side of an old shoe under the fabric and shoved the magnet in, put a second magnet it my sock and tried to get it to stick to my foot. It did but not very well, so I stopped and came here. I'm sure there are strong magnets, better ways to embed the magnet without burying it under .25in of fabric, etc. so I'm curious if it is even possible before continuing.

Comment: @WillO I dunno maybe some [hypdrophobic socks?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnMPh-eTBow). One step at a time..

Comment: I put your comment  in the text, I think it might stop other people asking the same question.  But if you are going to make terrible jokes like the one above, someone will put the boot in on your question...

Answer (score 0):

The whole concept with steel plates is unlikely to go much of anywhere for the simple reason that steel is ferromagnetic (this is *why* it works for shielding, so no getting away from this), so it would be very difficult to pull the steel plate off the magnet: you'd have more luck just pulling really hard to get the socks off.

The mechanism you describe wouldn't work: the steel plates would slide over the magnet without any force at all because they're attracted to it.

You'd probably also have trouble keeping the shoes and socks "minimal" with all the magnets/metal you'd need in there.

Comment: I'm going to second the steel plate being a bad idea. That said, I could imagine that there is a range of magnet strengths where the shoe stays attached, but you can still get your foot off if you need to.

Comment: @JahanClaes I'm not so sure. The force it takes to, for instance, pull your shoe out of the mud is surprisingly large. More than you'd probably want to tug on your shoe every time you want to take it off at least ;)